# Android: How to hide sign-in and sign-up option and enabled logout option in Navigation View using **Volley**

Tags: java, android, android-volley

The process for login and sign up is *Volley*. I want to remove sign in and sign up option when user perform anyone successfully and want to visible **log_out** menu item which I declared as invisible. Is there any way to make sign in and up invisible through out all the navigation drawers in this app?

This activity getting successful response in  **jsonObject form**

**LogIn.java**

```
 public class LogIn extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

// declare the variables

private EditText email ,password;
private Button btn_login;
private ProgressBar loading;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // setting variables

    loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    //btn_log_out = findViewById(R.id.log_out);
    TextView link_register = findViewById(R.id.link_regist);




    // click listenr for logging a user

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String mPass = password.getText().toString().trim();

            if(!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()){
                LogIn(mEmail, mPass);
            }else {
                email.setError("Please insert an e-mail");
                password.setError("Please insert a password");
            }
        }
    });

    link_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LogIn.this,Registration.class));
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}



private void LogIn(final String email, final String password) {

    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    String URL_LOGIN = "https://maknam.com/Portal2/apis/login.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                        if (success.equals("1")) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {

                                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                //noinspection unused
                                String name = object.getString("name").trim();
                                //noinspection unused,unused
                                String email = object.getString("email").trim();

                                Intent lg = new Intent(LogIn.this,
                                        Home.class);
                                startActivity(lg);

                                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Error"+ e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Error"+ error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    )


    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;

        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);




}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.log_in, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This activity also registered in **jsonObject** which shows the *error* or
*successfully* event

**Registration.Java**

```
   public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

// declare variables
private EditText name;
private EditText email;
private EditText password;
private Button btn_register;
private ProgressBar loading;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    EditText c_password = findViewById(R.id.c_password);
    btn_register = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    // click view for register a new user

    btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Register();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}


private void Register(){
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_register.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    final String name = this.name.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = this.email.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = this.password.getText().toString().trim();

    String URL_REGST = "http://maknam.com/Portal2/apis/register.php";
    //String URL_REGST = "http://192.168.1.103/android_register_login/register.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_REGST, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                if (success.equals("1")) {

                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Registration Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Registration Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_register.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Registration Error" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_register.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name",name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;

        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   //functionality for backpress
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.registration, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**Log Out** menu is *invisible* by default.

**activity_login.drawer**

```
 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item

        android:id="@+id/nav_products"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24px_product"
        android:title="Products"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/verify_product"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_48dp"
        android:title="Verify A Product"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <item android:id="@+id/log_in"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_box_black_48dp"
        android:title="Log In"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:icon="@drawable/reg_black_48dp"
        android:title="Sign Up"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/recent_verified"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_history_black_48dp"
        android:title="History"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/discussion"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum_black_48dp"
        android:title="Ulema's Discussion"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_48dp"
        android:title="Notifications"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/contact_us"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts_black_48dp"
        android:title="Contact Us"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_48dp"
        android:title="Settings"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/report_problem"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_report_black_48dp"
        android:title="Report A Problem"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/log_out"
        android:icon="@drawable/product_5"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        android:visible="false" />
</group>
```

**activity_registration.drawer**

```
same as acitvity_login.drawer
```

Comment: what does that mean ? .drawer

Comment: are those files menu layouts or layouts included in a drawer ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
private Menu menu;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout, menu);
    return true;
}

private void toogleVisiblityOfMenuItem(boolean isVisible, int itemId){
    menu.findItem(itemId).setVisible(isVisible);
}
```

Comment: this method **onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)** is already define in every class due to be a *navigation activity*.

Comment: then whats the problem. just initalize a menu variable in that override method and then you can esily access its item like i have done

Comment: Dear, you are not getting my point. I said,I have already method **onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)** method so, how can I make its replica?. the problem which I am facing is I want to hide **sign in** and **sign up** menus and make **Log Out** visible.